# What is the logic or algorithm for the following from HackerEarth?

Tags: algorithm

Hackers love bits, so does Alex. Alex has just started his career as hacker and found a special binary array 
A
A (containing 
0
s
 and 
1
s
).

In one operation, he can choose any two positions in the array, and can swap their values. He has to perform exactly one operation and maximize the length of the subarray containing only 
1
s
.

As Alex is a newbie in his field, help him for the same, and output the required length of the sub array containing only 
1
s
1s.

Input Format:

First line consists of one integer 
N, denoting the number of elements in the array.

Second line consists of N space-separated integers, denoting the elements of the array.

Output Format:

Print the required length of the sub array containing only 
1
s
1s.

Input Constraints:

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 100
1 ≤ N ≤ 1000 ≤ A[i] ≤ 1
```

Input:

```
5
1 1 1 0 1
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: It's kind of confusing that it mentions binary strings at first, and then gives an example with a non binary string, but the logic should be the same. Try to find the longest string of ones you can, but keep in mind you can ignore a single non-1 value, as long as there is another 1 in the string somewhere to replace it with.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? The non binary thing was a typo I guess. I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

General algorithm:

Have a variable, inSub, that keeps track of the substring you are looking at. Its value will be -1 at first, indicating that you are not looking at a particular substring atm.

Iterate through the string until you find a 1. The index of this 1 will be the new value of inSub.

Also have a variable, hitZero (initialized to False), which keeps track of if the current substring has encountered a zero yet. This is because one zero can be replaced by a one, assuming there is another one in the whole list. If a zero is hit and hitZero is False, it turns to True. If hitZero is already True, you will need to store the substring's length in a list SubList, inSub will be set to -1, and hitZero will be False again.

At the end of this you will have a list of substring lengths. If there are multiple substrings in the list, the answer will be the longest substring (because you can take a one from one of the other substrings). If there is only one substring, the answer will be the *longest contiguous string of 1's in the substring. (Edited)*

Comment: Yes I understand it. But how did you even think about it? I just need to know your thought process. I mean how did you come up with this algorithm. I am just a mediocre. Thank you very much btw. :) And what if the input is 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1

Comment: Im not sure how to explain my through process exactly, it is just like counting a string of 1's, except you have to account for being able to swap two numbers. There are many ways to write this algorithm, this is just the one that my brain comes up with.  With that input, it would come up with two substrings, one with a length of 7 and one of 1. Since there are multiple substrings, the zero in the first one can replaced, so the answer is 7.

Comment: Please check the edit at the bottom: I realized in a situation like 11011, my  imaginary program would have returned 4 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you what thought process you can use to solve this problem.

Whenever you see a problem, try to come up with some test cases in your mind.

For this particular question, any of the following mentioned test cases could be a good starting points.

```
Example 1:- 

Input:
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 

Output
4
```

In the above example, you can clearly see that there is no swap possible and therefore the output would be 4.

```
Example 2:-

Input
1 1 1 1 1 1 

Output 
6
```

In the above example also no swap is possible, as there is no sub-string separated by 0, so your answer is basically equal to the length of the whole string.

```
Example 3:-

Input
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 

Output
5
```

In the above example, you can see one swap of one from the first contiguous strings of one with the zero present near the other strings will give you, your answer.

So now you have three good examples covering most of the corner case.

Look at the comment below and above algorithm to get a good view about how to solve this problem.

Thanks to Carl for reviewing my algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What about a situation like 11101110001?

Comment: @CarlShiles good catch .... ya missed that corner case ...